# Generating Bytecode for Program for which a Compiler was build using ANTLR 4 with Java

Tags: java, compiler-construction, antlr4, bytecode, cil

I am currently developing a compiler for a particular programming language with ANTLR 4 and Java and now I would like to generate Bytecode or CIL for any program written in that particular languaje but I am not sure where to begin.

I have searched many pages but unable to find any tutorials and whatever example I find does not properly explain the proceedures. I have seen that a helpful library is `asm` but I don't understand it's implementation.

Can anyone assist me as to the the preferred library and it's implementation with a possible example?

Comment: One trick is to first generate java, compile that and decompile it with javap, and use that to create a second bytecode compiler with ASM. However just decompiling with javap might do too. And you may use ASM to replace parts of the class. Sample code you have to search yourself. Writing ASM cde to intercept some call of some test class might be a good entry point.

Comment: @JoopEggen The problem is I do not have a java file to compile. What I have is a file with code from another languaje in which I have developed a compiler using ANTLR 4 which validates and executes that code. Now what I want to do is from that be able to generate the bytecode for the instructions of that language.

Comment: I just suggested that one could first write a compiler to java, decompile its product so every construct is clear, and then write a compiler to byte code. Or alternatively write small java code snippets, compile and decompile in order to have working target code, to use with ASM. Otherwise there are two questions: 1. did you apply ASM correctly, and 2. is the generated code correct.

Comment: The starting point is [The Java® Virtual Machine Specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se13/html/index.html), as you have to understand how it works, to generate code for it. It contains a description of the class file format (chapter 4) and some examples how Java constructs map to bytecode (chapter 3) which help you getting into the right thinking. I’ve never used any tutorials on that topic. They only repeat the information (in the best case). Sometimes they are incorrect, sloppy, or outdated and you have to refer to the authoritative source anyway.

Comment: Generating java code and then generating java byte code from that might not help as you have to care about additional java specific restrictions to the JVM.

Comment: One very good tutorial is at <https://tomassetti.me/generating-bytecode/>, generating bytecode is part 8 of the whole series that walks you through everything. The code is in kotlin but should map quite well to java.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an ANTLR4 question, however the approach is relatively simple: study the executor, which will later execute your byte code. Find a document that describes the bytecode for this particular machine. Then write a listener or visitor to spill out that code.

Commenters here seem to assume you want to generate Java bytecode, but I'm actually not sure about that, since you mention Java only in the context of parsing, not code generation.

Comment: I like to add that best starting point is to generate some byte code by hand to learn how things work. Than try to fit you language syntax to the learned concepts.

Comment: I have already created the interpreter using ANTLR4 (Visitor method) but what I am trying to do now is for the language I am interpreting, be able to load a file with code written in that language and generate bytecode for that code which can later be executed.